# How do I change the actioncable default path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have an ecommerce website that sells cables, and as such I'd like to use `/cable`, `/cables` etc in my base routes.

Unfortunately activecable uses the `/cable` path by default. Is there any way I can change this?

So far I've tried changing (to no avail) in my `/config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://www.example.com/actioncable"
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `config.action_cable.mount_path = '/websocket'` as per [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#configuration)

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes.rb` :

Add this line:

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/your_route_for_action_cable'
```